# Navigate To a Video's Parent Playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

When viewing a video, and the video's up-loader added/uploaded it as part of a playlist. From the video page, how can I easily reach the entire parent playlist for said video?

**Some Notes**

The `Next Up` video does show the next video in the playlist correctly, but I want see the entire "list" of videos in the playlist.

When navigating to a video from a playlist, it retains the playlist for easy navigation.

I can navigate to the up-loader's page, then click on Playlists, then search for the playlist, but this is cumbersome.

Comment: In case this feature exists in YouTube it would probably need to display a list of all playlists including the video. A single video could belong to several playlists. I'm not sure YouTube would consider any one of those playlists to be more important than the others.

Comment: I understand that, that's why I specifically mentioned up-loader's playlist.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do this myself. The following Javascript code, when run in the browser console of a Youtube video page, grabs the title and channel name, submits a search to Youtube with those elements, and parses out the top resulting playlist ID. A more robust solution would use the Youtube API but I didn't want to bother with setting and storing API keys here.

(Caveat: Seems to have trouble with excessively complex video titles)

```
function captureYouTubeData() {
    let videoTitleElement = document.querySelector('h1.style-scope.ytd-watch-metadata yt-formatted-string.style-scope.ytd-watch-metadata');
    let videoTitle = videoTitleElement ? videoTitleElement.innerText : null;

    let channelNameElement = document.querySelector('yt-formatted-string.ytd-channel-name');
    let channelName = channelNameElement ? channelNameElement.innerText : null;

    let data = {
        "videoTitle": videoTitle,
        "channelName": channelName
    };

    return data;
}

async function findFirstPlaylistId(videoTitle, channelOwner) {
    // Constructing the search URL
    const baseUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/results';
    const query = encodeURIComponent(`"${channelOwner}" "${videoTitle}"`);
    const searchUrl = `${baseUrl}?search_query=${query}`;

    // Fetch the content
    const response = await fetch(searchUrl);
    const htmlText = await response.text();

    // Extract ytInitialData from the HTML
    const ytInitialDataRegex = /var ytInitialData = (.*?);\s*<\/script>/s;
    const match = ytInitialDataRegex.exec(htmlText);
    
    if (!match) {
        console.error("Failed to extract ytInitialData");
        return null;
    }

    const ytInitialData = JSON.parse(match[1]);

    // Recursive function to extract the playlistId
    function findPlaylistId(data) {
        if (data && data.playlistRenderer && data.playlistRenderer.playlistId && data.playlistRenderer.playlistId.length > 2) {
            return data.playlistRenderer.playlistId;
        }

        if (typeof data === 'object') {
            for (let key in data) {
                const result = findPlaylistId(data[key]);
                if (result) return result;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    return findPlaylistId(ytInitialData);
}

let videoData = captureYouTubeData();
findFirstPlaylistId(videoData.videoTitle, videoData.channelName).then(id => console.log('Playlist: ', id));
```